# Blackberry compass integration

Tags: java, blackberry, native-code, compass-geolocation

I need to integrate compass in my application to show the direction in which user is moving. show latitude and longitude.

I really appreciate any help, suggestions.

Thanks,

tej.

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/29251/Magnetometer_1558126_11.jsp

Comment: @MisterSmith this code will not give compass ui?

Comment: @user3209583 Use the APIs to get compass data and visualize them in your application

Comment: @user3209583 No, but you can use a [`CompassField`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/lbs/compass/CompassField.html)

Comment: @MisterSmith will this CompassField work in Blackberry sdk6.0.0 or i have to check with Blackberry sdk7.0.0 ?

Comment: @user3209583 It was added in API 7